# Is there a way to reverse my own review of an edit?

Tags: support, review-queues

I rejected an open edit on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29681391/solving-pde-with-matlab), but then realized that my rejection reason wasn't correct - the editing user had formatted the code, but in the markdown view it appeared as though the code had already been formatted correctly.

Is there a way to reverse my reject vote?

**Edit:** The "duplicate" is not actually a duplicate, because it's about a different topic (vote on a question) that *is actually actionable* by users. In that case, the user voted to leave open, but they can still go directly to the question and vote to close.

Comment: Edit was approved anyway, so everything is all right.

Comment: @Roombatron5000 - see my edit. Not a duplicate, because that represents a review action that can be corrected.

Comment: The last line of the duplicate question's answer says `You cannot actually change your review` . There is no way to reverse your review in any queue. If you really want to make up for it, you could find a good post of that user and upvote it.

Comment: @Roombatron5000 - It goes on to say `...  but you can still "fix" it by taking the appropriate action on the post itself (voting to close in your case).` - there is still an action the user can take that will *correct* the mistake they made in the review.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, there is no way for you to undo or change the vote.

Comment: Ok, thanks. It pays to flip between markdown and rendered view.