# Rollback/Revert approval of a suggested edit?

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request

I accidentally approved this [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7814565). Which is spam but for some reason I accidentally clicked on the "Approve" button.  I know that other people will reject it and in the end this edit will be rejected.

Yes i know that i can review suggestion, but is there anyway I can revert my "Approve" action?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I change my review of a question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258820/can-i-change-my-review-of-a-question) and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290470/is-there-a-way-to-reverse-my-own-review-of-an-edit

Comment: it is different. In that answer suggested to review not says how to rollback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change your review, this is to ensure that people don't change their failed review Audits.

But don't worry, the edit was rejected by others.

In case somehow the edit got approved, you could just edit and remove that part ( or a roll back ). But there is no way to change a review. If you hit approve, that's it, no changing that.

So in short, you cannot revert your "Approve" action. You will just have to hope others don't approve it, and if it is approved somehow, then edit it and remove those changes.